# Angular Material: How close overlay's backdrop also on right click?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

How close the overlay's backdrop (opened by [MatMenu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) or [MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)) also on right click globally (without matMenu/matDialog reference)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click has a default action which takes function by the browser itself.

I recommend not to override that functionality. Just add a listener for `contextmenu` event:

```
document.getElementByTagName('body')[0]
  .addEventListener('contextmenu', (ev) => {
    this.matMenu.closeMenu();
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Another method**

Open the matdialog :

```
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(template);
```

Listen contextmenu action :

```
<div (contextmenu)="closeDialog($event)"></div>
```

Close method :

```
closeDialog(event) {
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```